# Export json file from Neo4j database using PHP

Tags: php, json, node.js

For that, I used the following code:

```
$result = $client->sendCypherQuery('MATCH (n) RETURN n')->getResult();
$nodes = [];
foreach ($result->getNodes() as $node) {
    $nodes[] = [
        'id' => $node->getId(),
        'labels' => $node->getLabels(),
        'properties' => $node->getProperties()
    ];
}

var_dump(json_encode($nodes));
```

But I get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getNodes() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\PhpProjectNeo4j1\index.php

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a function on an object which is empty or does not exists. First print the result of the returned query.

Probably the query does not return any result, **but first you need to connect to the neo4j database**:

Here is an example of how you can do it:

https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-php-neoclient/blob/fe5fd9222945ca8e9efc4ab3cac6b743f2ff8b24/index.php

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->addConnection('default', $cnx['scheme'], $cnx['host'], $cnx['port'], true, $cnx['user'], $cnx['pass'])
    ->setAutoFormatResponse(true)
    ->setDefaultTimeout(20)
    ->build();

$result = $client->sendCypherQuery('MATCH (n) RETURN n')->getResult();
var_dump($result);
```

A common way is to test the returned result emptiness before traversing the array.

```
if (!empty($result)) {
    foreach ($result->getNodes() as $node) {
        $nodes[] = [
            'id' => $node->getId(),
            'labels' => $node->getLabels(),
            'properties' => $node->getProperties()
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you're right. var_dump($result); --> retrurn null but when I execute MATCH (n) RETURN n in Neo4j console it's not null. It returned a graph

Comment: First you need to connect to the neo4j database. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: That's ok now. for Edges, I used this code: foreach ($result->getRelationships() as $rel){
 
        $edges[] = [
            'source' => $nodesPositions[$rel->getStartNode()->getId()],
            'target' => $nodesPositions[$rel->getEndNode()->getId()]
        ];
    }
  
 var_dump(json_encode($edges));   But it returned string '[]'

Comment: This means that the query result is null. You need to debug what kind of response is returning the query.